# Why won't MySQL statement work?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, create-table

I am using PHPMyAdmin right now and I am creating a new table with these values below but it's not working and I can't see why at all.

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE  `database`.`hub_attendance_lessons` (

`id` BIGINT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`lesson_id` BIGINT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`course_id` BIGINT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`student_id` BIGINT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`date` BIGINT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
`attended` BOOL( 2 ) UNSIGNED NULL ,
`absent` BOOL( 2 ) UNSIGNED NULL ,
`excused_absent` BOOL( 2 ) UNSIGNED NULL ,
`late` BOOL( 2 ) UNSIGNED NULL ,
`excused_late` BOOL( 2 ) UNSIGNED NULL
)
 ENGINE = MYISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci 
 COMMENT =  'stores the attendance of all lessons for all students';
```

MySQL said:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>        MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(2) UNSIGNED NULL, `absent` 
>       BOOL(2) UNSIGNED NULL, `excused_absent` BOOL(2) UNSI' at line 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BOOL` and `BOOLEAN` are just shorthand for `TINYINT(1)`. It makes no sense to have a BOOL(2). Remove all lengths of 2 for your booleans.

Comment: it does that automatically. All my length fields for bool are empty